# Inner product properties $\langle x,\lambda y \rangle = \overline{\lambda}\langle x, y \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra

I do not understand some basic property of inner-product, i.e why its true?

$$\langle x,\lambda y \rangle = \overline{\lambda}\langle x,  y \rangle$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Exactly it is a complex inner product space.

Answer (score 2):

Because (complex) inner products are defined so that

$$\langle \lambda x,y\rangle=\lambda\langle x,y\rangle$$

and

$$\langle x,y\rangle=\overline{\langle y,x\rangle},$$

we can deduce that

$$\langle x,\lambda y\rangle=\overline{\langle \lambda y,x\rangle}=\overline{\lambda\langle y,x\rangle}=\overline{\lambda}\overline{\langle y,x\rangle}=\overline{\lambda}\langle x,y\rangle.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is just part of the definition of an inner product on a complex vector space.

To see one example which you might agree is reasonable: do you agree that in the complex plane you would like $\langle z,z\rangle = |z|^2$?  If so, do you see why pulling out a factor of $z$ from one of the two slots and a factor of $\bar{z}$ from the other slot is desirable?